# Limit Definition of a Derivative - Unfactorable?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I was tutoring a student today and had to solve the following: $f'(2)$ given that $f(x) = 2x^5-5x^2$ using the limit definition of the derivative $$f'(a) = \lim_{b\to a}\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$

This lead me to $\lim_{b\to 2}\frac{2b^5-5b^2-(2(2^5)-5(2^2))}{b-2} = \lim_{b\to 2}\frac{2b^5-5b^2-44}{b-2}$  which gives a $0/0$ limit (as expected).

I know somehow this needs to be factored, and likely cancel the $b-2$ term in the denominator, but for the life of me, I can't figure out how.  Obviously the answer should be 180 (just taking the derivative normally) but I can't figure out how to get there using the limit definition!

Comment: Use polynomial long division. By the way, the final answer is $140$, not $180$.

Comment: don't multiply out, keep the fifth powers together and factor that part, and keep the second powers together and factor that part.

Comment: $b^5-a^5 = (b-a) (\dots)$ ....

Comment: You got a $0/0$ limit when you substituted $b=2$, which means the numerator has a $b-2$ factor. Factorise the numerator by long division.

Answer (score 2):

This problem would be easier to derive with the other definition of the derivative, $f'(x) = \lim\limits_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}$. So my general advice for this is to approach it using the above-mentioned definition. However, I will tell you how to solve it using your method.

You've gotten to the point where:

$$f'(2) = \lim\limits_{b \rightarrow 2} \frac{2b^5-5b^2-44}{b-2}$$

There are a few important notes we must make before we can attempt to solve this. First, we must establish that $f(x)$ is differentiable because all polynomials are. Therefore, we know that the derivate exists. Second, we must assume that the limit has been correctly simplified into the above form *(which it has)*, so all criteria are met for the next step.

Because the derivative exists, we know that $(b-2)$ must cancel. Therefore, one of the zeros of the numerator must be $2$, so that once it's factored, $(b-2)$ will cancel. We can confirm using the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) that 2 could be a possibility for a zero of the numerator. To fully confirm it and factor it, we can use [synthetic division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_division). I cannot type out the process of that, so I'm attaching [this](https://ibb.co/YZjRhsJ).

Because the last term is $0$, this confirms that $2$ is, in fact, a zero of the numerator. We can take the rest of our terms and arrange them into a polynomial to get the following, factored limit:

$$f'(2) = \lim\limits_{b \rightarrow 2} \frac{(b-2)(2b^4 + 4b^3 + 8b^2 + 11b + 22)}{b-2}$$

$(b-2)$ cancels, so we are left with the following, easily-evaluated limit:

$$f'(2) = \lim\limits_{b \rightarrow 2} (2b^4 + 4b^3 + 8b^2 + 11b + 22) = \boxed{140}$$

*You mentioned in your original post that the answer should be $180$, but the correct answer is actually $140$. We can confirm using the power rule: $\frac{d}{dx}[2x^5 - 5x^2] = 10x^4 - 10x$. Plugging in 2, $10((2)^4-2) = 10(16 - 2) = 10(14) = 140$.*

Comment: You don't actually need to note all those things to solve this. All you need to say to your self is: *The simplest way this could work out is if $b-2$ is a factor of the numerator. So let's try long division to see if it works.*

Comment: @LeeMosher I agree, but I just included it as a way to show the mental notes I was making about the problem that led me to the answer. I feel it outlines rational thinking way better than just posting the plain process with no background information. Otherwise, it makes people think, "Yeah I guess I could have done that, but I could never actually stumble across that solution myself."

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$2b^5−5b^2−44 = 2b^5 -2 \cdot 32 - 5b^2 + 20 = 2(b-2)(b^4 + 2b^3 + 4b^2 + 8b + 16) - 5(b-2)(b+2)$.

Thus,
$\lim_{b\to2}\frac{2b^5−5b^2−44}{b-2} = \lim_{b\to2} 2(b^4 + 2b^3 + 4b^2 + 8b + 16) - 5(b+2)= 2\cdot 5 \cdot 16 - 5 \cdot 4 = 140$, which checks out.